# Can't get a list with the .gitignore files in my project

Tags: git, gitignore, ls

i'm in a project for my class and i need to list all files that a are being ignored by my gitignored files from a sub folder. i used  git check-ignore, but i don't get the hidden files (files that begin with .

here is the question :

> Write a short shell script that will return the list of existing ignored files in your git repository that are currently present in your local repository.

if that helps the git version we are using in this project is 2.20

Comment: How are you checking with `check-ignore`? Reading the man page, it sounds like it does exactly what you need it to do. It takes a list of paths to check, either read from a file or from stdin. As long as you pass the paths of your hidden files, they should be output (given that they are excluded by your .gitignore file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git check-ignore` probably doesn't work like you expect to. From the doc:

> For each pathname given via the command-line or from a file via --stdin, check whether the file is excluded by .gitignore

So you probably wanted to call `git check-ignore path/to/my/project` but it is not the way it is designed. Instead, you have to do the following

```
cd path/to/my/project
git check-ignore ignored-file.txt
# Output: ignored-file.txt
git check-ignore project-file.txt
# Output:
```

So, in bash, you can use `*` pattern matching to expand to all files in current dir and `**/*` for all files in current directory and its subdirectories. To include hidden files, `.*` or `**/.*` can be used:

```
git check-ignore **/* **/.*
```

You will get the full list of files actually ignored by .gitignore

Comment: Since `check-ignore` can read paths from stdin line by line, it's probably simple to use find: `find | git check-ignore --stdin`. This also avoids the problem of expanding too many paths and exceeding the `ARG_MAX` limit of your OS

Comment: @knittl I advise `find -type f`

Comment: @phd: `.gitignore` can contain directory paths. These won't show if find only outputs files. But yeah, depending on OP's requirements, only files might be of interest and directories not.

Comment: @knittl I never knew `git check-ignore` can display directories. Thank you for explaining!